# Maven: mvn --version java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, maven, classnotfoundexception

I have just installed new Maven into my new Fedora 17 64bit.

Details:

java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.7-b02, mixed mode)
```

javac -version

```
javac 1.6.0_32
```

echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32
```

echo $JRE_HOME

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre
```

echo $M2_HOME

```
/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
```

echo $M2

```
/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/bin:/home/bujaka/.local/bin:/home/bujaka/bin
```

which mvn

```
/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn
```

But mvn -version throws  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)                                                    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)                                          
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

P.S. I installed maven from apache site (not from fedora repos)

Comment: Are you online and can maven download its dependencies?

Comment: Yes I'm online, but maven doesn't starts and it even doesn't create a .m2 home folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MavenCli class is in maven-embedder. Are you behind a proxy?

```
  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

@See [Maven Proxy Settings](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies)

Comment: no I have no proxy and my proxy section in settings.xml is empty

Comment: /lib catalog was empty in maven.tar.gz archive. I downloaded maven.zip archive, where /lib catalog have nearly 30 .jar libraries and maven finally started. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

thanks `user1436170`, your last comment did the job for me as well:

```
/lib catalog was empty in maven.tar.gz archive.
```

When opening via krusader, lib folder in tar.gz file it was empty, but it contains jars when opening via ark.

Anyway zip works.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same issue.  Bujaka's comment and Peter Butkovic's answer get at the issue, but for the record here's my take on it and the solution I used.

I don't know what causes this, but sometimes the entire content of the /lib folder in your maven installation directory can become empty.  This may be the case when you get this error.

If you check your /lib folder and find that it is not empty, it is still possible (although unlikely) that a crucial file somehow got deleted.

If your maven installation used to work find and only started acting up recently, then the zipped archive you used was probably fine.  Here's what to do:

1. Rename your installation directory (or if you're brave, just delete it).
2. Get the original zipped archive. (If you're like me, it's still somewhere in your increasingly cluttered downloads folder.  If not you'll have to re-download it.)
3. Unzip said archive into the location of your original installation directory (which you either renamed or deleted).

Your maven installation should now work again.

Comment: Even if your /lib is not empty, try the above process. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this issue:
Go to maven official site i.e https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and download latest Apache maven. (Make sure you download Binary zip archive for windows user specially)

and set SYSTEM environment variable as:

```
MAVEN_HOME      C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.8.6

path            %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```