# Maven Error: The SLF4J binding actually used is not supported by Maven

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

Whenever I run a goal inside Maven, the first few lines I see are:

```
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:22 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.UnsupportedSlf4jBindingConfiguration activate
WARNING: The SLF4J binding actually used is not supported by Maven: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:22 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.UnsupportedSlf4jBindingConfiguration activate
WARNING: Maven supported bindings are:
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:22 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.UnsupportedSlf4jBindingConfiguration activate
WARNING: (from jar:file:/usr/local/bin/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar!/META-INF/maven/slf4j-configuration.properties)
- ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
- org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory
- org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory
```

Looking for a solution has led me to this [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5961), which suggests changing the `maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar`. I've tried changing the JAR which leads to Maven being in a completely unusable state (this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889445/maven-mvn-version-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)).

As Maven is right now, I think this bug not only prints the warning in the beginning of the output, but also adds a timestamp followed by Slf4Logger before every line as follows:

```
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:26 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger info
INFO: +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:26 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger info
INFO: +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:compile
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:26 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger info
INFO: +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
Mar 16, 2017 4:48:26 PM org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger info
INFO: |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
```

Has anybody else dealt with this issue? Is there another fix?

Comment: Could you share your pom?

Comment: I get this issue regardless of which project I'm using. For example, the basic project from apache (https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) is producing the same message.

Comment: Ok, what version of maven are you using? What jdk is ran with maven?

Comment: Maven 3.3.9, with Java 1.8.0_71. Running this all on Mac OSX 10.12.2